# Sorted NSIndexSet of sub array of NSArray

Tags: ios, sorting, nsarray, nsindexset

Let say I have `NSIndexSet` of array indexes.
I want to sort this `NSIndexSet` depends on `NSArray`.

So, let say we have array :

```
array = @[1,4,3,8,6,2,9];
```

and index set

```
indexSet :  (2,4,5,6)
```

so "sub array" of this indexes would be

```
subArray = @[3,6,2,9]
```

So what I would like to have is :

```
I have :
indexSet : (2,4,5,6)
array = @[1,4,3,8,6,2,9];
return indexSet : (5,2,4,6) --> this are sorted indexes of "sub array".
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: This will only create "sub" array, and doesn't return NSIndexSet of sorted indexes...

Comment: Sorry, misread. Forgot the last part of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't achieve what you want. `NSIndexSet` doesn't maintain an order separate from the order of the indexes themselves. It is always in index order.

You could build an array of number objects which you treat as indexes.

```
NSArray* array = /* ... */;
NSMutableArray* indexes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[indexSet enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    [indexes addObject:@(idx)];
}];
[indexes sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSNumber* obj1, NSNumber* obj2){
    NSUInteger index1 = obj1.unsignedIntegerValue;
    NSUInteger index2 = obj2.unsignedIntegerValue;
    id element1 = array[index1];
    id element2 = array[index2];
    return [element1 compare:element2];
}];
```